# insert data into Access on server A from SQLServer on server B

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-server

**Please note that I have replaced the actual server names with A and B as a precaution.**

I am trying to write data from SQL Server (on server B) to an Microsoft Access mdb file (on server A).

I have created a linked server on SQL Server that can write data to a test file on the same server (B) using the provider shown below:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't seem to setup a Linked server to write across to a different server, resulting in the following error: 
[image]

This is what I am trying to setup:
[image]

Security is set to 'Be made using the login's current security context'. I have access to the mdb file from both my machine on the network and from remote desktop onto both server A & server B, so I don't think it is a permission issue.

I can copy and paste the data source '\A\dep$\Data Workbench\Commercial\Pricing Project\PricingTest.mdb' into file explorer it finds it no problem.

Comment: The windows account that the SQL Server is using must have visibility to the file. Make sure it has privileges. Find which account it is by doing `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services` and checking the one for MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: `it finds it no problem.` you'll have to provide proof of that. `$` appears only in [administrative shares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share), eg disk letters and a couple other special use folders. There's no `dep$` folder. Even if `dep$` existed, it would only be visible to administrators.

Comment: Create a proper network share on the server instead of trying to use an administrative share.

Comment: @EzLo I am not sure how I would grant MSSQLSERVER access to that file, I have entered my own credentials into the security tab so shouldn't that provide the right permission?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately I have no authority over the network share, the group policy and Active directory is not my department. The dep$ is assigned to Q drive but i Have been instructed to use '\\A\dep$\Data Workbench\Commercial\Pricing Project\PricingTest.mdb' rather than Q:\\Data Workbench etc...

Comment: There's no `dep$` administrative share. Only *administrators of a machine* can access administrative shares. SQL Server's service account is not an administrator so it will never be able to use an administrative share. If you want to be able to export data, create proper shared folders to which the service account, or whatever executes the export scripts, has permission to write

Answer (score 0):

First try to use the `Q:` drive directly to see if the link server works. If it works, then you need to look at the issue from the network(privileges) level. If it doesn't you need to look at your linked server configuration. `dep$` is actually a hidden Windows share, meaning it will not show up in the file explorer when browsing the network. You can access it if you have the necessary privileges and know the correct path. You need to verify that the user running under the SQL Server service has access to this share.

Have a look at this article regarding granting the SQL Server user Read/Write access to the Temp folder of the SQL Server service user: https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/setup-a-linked-server-to-ms-access-from-sql-server-beat-the-errors/